# Scrollview in NestedScrollview is not working kitkat 4.4

Tags: android, nestedscrollview

Scrollview in nestedScrollview is working fine with other versions of android but in kitkat it is not working.
I have addded onItemClick() function to nestedscrollview. while clicking on nested scrollview only scrollview(parent) working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
   >

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/parentScrollview"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/navyBlue"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/remarksLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="@dimen/header_left_padding_size"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remarks_report_white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/remarksTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/remarksLogo"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/header_text_size"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:weightSum="6">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/datedTitles"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/navyBlue"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sub_header_text_size"
                    android:text=""/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fromTitle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/left_right_border_white"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sub_header_text_size"
                    android:text=""/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailsTitle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/navyBlue"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sub_header_text_size"
                    android:text=""/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:isScrollContainer="true"
                    android:id="@+id/childNestedScrollView"
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                    android:fillViewport="true">
                    <com.iflytechsoft.studentsuccess.utils.studentsuccessutils.ListViewForEmbeddingInScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/remarksListView"
                        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

                        android:background="@drawable/background_white_border_navyblue"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        />
                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/announcementDetailLayout"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@color/navyBlue"
                android:weightSum="6">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dated"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/navyBlue"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sub_header_text_size"
                    android:text=""/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/from"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:background="@drawable/left_right_border_white"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sub_header_text_size"
                    android:text=""/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subject"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3.7"
                    android:background="@color/navyBlue"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sub_header_text_size"
                    android:text=""/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ir.noghteh.JustifiedTextView xmlns:noghteh="http://noghteh.ir"
                android:id="@+id/details"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                noghteh:textSize="@dimen/sub_header_text_size"
                android:background="@drawable/background_white_border_navyblue"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```